# vertices are not selected properly, and i cant recalculate normals

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, normals

vertices,face dots are not selected properly, and also i cant recalculate normals.this is an appended model from a file edited in b3d 2.81, which i need to use it in b3d 2.79b because the game engine, then i got this problem, someones know to fix it? i have seen this before happening when appending a model from 2.79b to 2.80/2.81

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots here you go [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6902" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6902/)

Comment: guysss help meeee

Comment: I don't see what's the problem, could you please describe more precisely? I can select faces or vertices, flip normals, etc... there might be som weight problem here and there though.

Comment: @moonboots is in the mesh the problem as i said the vertices looks selected like in the upper capture, they usually look like that, see face mode and you will see the dots only selected, if no i dont know whats happening then, but as i said this model was appended to 2.79 from a file created from b3d 2.81...i recalculate the normal and does nothing in the black sided faces, but if i select those faces and click in flip normal its get fixed but is not normal that i have to select them individually to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you're talking about is only a problem of mesh display: In the 3D View, press <kbd>N</kbd> to display the right panel, then in the *Mesh Display* panel, enable *Faces*, *Edges* and *Crease* as it is supposed by default? In 2.8 it will be in the header menu > *Viewport Overlays* panel.

[image]

Comment: damn thank you i didnt realize that!